# Quality blocks enabled for questions

Tags: discussion, post-ban, low-quality-posts

Questions are the lifeblood of any Stack Exchange site. But asking *good* questions can be difficult, for some people entirely too difficult to bother with. When the Trilogy sites reached traffic levels that made manual review and filtering of questions burdensome for the good folks *answering* them, we began building systems to [detect and slow down the folks who weren't putting any effort into learning and improving over time](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/):

> We believe asking questions on our site is a privilege, not a right. If, after a few fair attempts, you haven’t been able to prove that your contributions to Stack Overflow make it at least … not-worse … then we reserve the right to refuse your questions. If we don’t do our part to cull the bad questions, then we risk alienating the true experts who provide what really matters: the answers!

Mathematics has reached traffic levels where this sort of rate-limiting and outright blocking of questions makes sense, so we've enabled quality blocks here as well. These blocks are based on the community's collective rating of posts from both a user's account and other accounts on the same IP address, thus limiting the ability of folks to abuse the community by just creating new accounts. Blocked users are directed to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), which explains what that person must do to lift the block. Moderators have access to information on whether or not a given user would be blocked, as well as whether or not they've previously encountered the block, for those cases where it is desirable to provide one-on-one support.

#### What you can do to help

Quality blocks are based on the community's rating of questions and answers, therefore the most useful things you can do are:

> - if you see a great, thoughtfully asked, well researched question, vote it up — *please*! Great questions are an art!
> - if you see an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended question that you feel was asked in bad faith … vote it down.
> - anything in between that’s salvageable, edit it!

Don't worry about the exact details of the algorithm used for blocking - in general, it's fairly conservative as far as who or what gets blocked. As always, vote your conscience and encourage new members to participate constructively.

Comment: Is this enabled on meta too? (I hope it's not, because downvotes work differently here).

Comment: No; this has never been enabled on any meta site beyond MSO. If the mods find the volume of crappy questions here overwhelming it is *possible* to enable it, but I'm not sure it'd be useful.

Comment: Good to know. Also, I think that the [help center page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) could use  some customization. It sends users to MSO formatting sandbox instead of [ours](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/370/). Most formatting issues here involve MathJax, which can't be tested at MSO.  The relevance of "How do I format my code blocks?" on Math is questionable. I wonder if our mods have or can be given edit access to this help center page?

Comment: Excellent point, @user. I've added links to those resources and marked the page as moderator-editable.

Comment: What happens when the user is an unregistered user which has more accounts than natural numbers? (And as history tells us, that's not a hypothetical case...)

Comment: Chances are, the IP-address fallback applies in that case, @Asaf.

Comment: Well, I sure hope so!

Comment: For the record, this action contributes its bit to the alienation of at least one user who provides a few answers now and then. Probably not a large bit, since I’ll probably not be constantly reminded that it exists, but a bit.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit, @Brian?

Comment: I don’t know that there's really anything more to say: I dislike anything that (in my opinion) makes the site less friendly to fairly new users. I think that this qualifies, and I don’t think that it’s needed. I recognize that I’m not a typical user, or even a typical regular, and I also don’t pretend to be entirely in sympathy with the SE philosophy, so I don’t expect my opinion to carry much weight, but I couldn’t let the *risk alienating* line pass without comment.

Comment: Do you notify the user once the block is in place, or first have them waste the time of attempting to post and then find out by the "unpleasant surprise" method?   If your identification system is robust enough that changing user accounts will not easily defeat it, there is no loss in providing that information ASAP.  And if not, the blocked users can defeat it easily after you have triply incentivized them to do so, once by blocking and again by wasting their time, and yet again by doing this when they have a query they want answered.

Comment: Fair enough, @Brian. There's certainly room for improvement in how we treat new users; at the same time, I've seen frustration with a handful of exceptionally annoying users boil over into interactions with new folks who've done nothing majorly wrong - I believe there's value in giving folks a few chances to prove themselves first, and this system reflects that; but there's real harm in making it too easy for folks who *continually* attract the ire of the community.

Comment: From what I've seen, folks willing to put the effort into working around it are at least *somewhat* more likely to put effort into correcting whatever problem led them to get blocked in the first place, @zyx. If that *does* happen... Well, great!

Comment: I am concerned about how this new feature may be used by people with an unusually low pain threshold.

Comment: @André: There is also the possibility that the pain threshold has dropped to a low level exactly because it is being constantly pushed. Hopefully with this tool in place some of the open wounds can heal. After a healing period I hope that every little poke will not cause an outraged yelp of pain. Having said that let's try and be responsible. The existence of THE TOOL does not grant us a license to kill.

Comment: I see many questions at an "advanced" level that are just as fundamentally obvious (at their level) as lower level questions that quickly get closed (Oops, *held*).  These "advanced" questions are often clearly of the homework kind, though usually the question poser is sophisticated enough not to say so.

Comment: @André: That is true. The difference in attitude towards those (guilty as charged) is likely explained by the fact that such questions don't get viewed by as many members. Consequently they don't skew the reputation game to the same extent as their lower level cousins.

Comment: I am tempted to suggest that all those fundamentally obvious questions (at their respective levels) be turned into community wiki.

Comment: I guess the answer to my question is that there is no notification before the time of the blocked posting.  While this could be for implementation reasons, such as not checking the permission until the post time (after all, the parameters like up- and down-vote counts can change until that moment), there is an accumulation of the parameters over time to a point where they go well into the blocked range.  In addition to the previously stated problems, a natural reaction from a blocked user not totally new to the site would be "why did you not tell me earlier?".  Especially the cooperative ones.

Comment: @zyx: blocked folks are notified of this fact when they click the "Ask Question" button at the top-right of any page. There's been some debate over whether or not we should notify them ahead of time, but my feeling is that this would only add drama - as you note, the factors affecting the block can change at any time, so there's a reasonable chance of being wrong in a rather cruel fashion. I *do* think it would be a good to *warn* folks that they *might* be blocked in the future when they're asking a new question after their previous questions were poorly-received.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant: *if* you have such a feature (which can cause other problems besides bad feelings of affected users and some fraction of the unaffected), *then* when the factors/parameters start moving into the red zone, have some type of notice to the user.

Comment: The description suggests that a lot of 0-vote questions could trigger a block. I don't think this is appropriate. 0-vote posts tend to be reasonable ones that most people don't understand or don't happen to find interesting. Also, part of the structure of this seems to break the reputation system: if someone writes a lot of good answers, I think they've earned the leeway to ask some really awful questions. In fact, even if someone writes *only* bad questions, but great answers, I think it's quite reasonably to let them keep asking if that will keep them around.

Comment: @dfeuer: the actual blocking logic takes a lot of different factors into account, including well-received answers. 0-score questions aren't a problem in and of themselves; they become a problem when you have a large number of questions and 0 is the *highest* score though...